# How to Mosaic Images using ArcMap when coordinate system is undefined?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-9.3, image-mosaic

I have images which are not Georeferance with any coordinate system and i want to mosaic those images in ArcMap 9.3

Comment: Is there no georeference at all? So all the images come up on top of each other... you're going to have to georeference them somehow or mosaic in Photoshop, GIMP etc..

Comment: If they aren't georeferenced and you don't want to do them individually, then the process you're looking for is called photo stitching. Several image editing softwares have this capability, but you'll want to be sure to use one that has a planar method since most are aimed at doing perspective-based photographs.

Answer (score 2):

To Mosaic non georeferenced images using ArcMap may not be possible at all. I Suggest you use online base-maps if you know the locality of the images, look for duplicate points from the image and an online base-map then use those values to first georeference so that you can Mosaic